# Cast object to recive it as model in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to receive a model in my `PartialView` that is within the model of the parent view, it is complicated to explain, I will try to do it with a bit of code

**Model A**

```
public class example
{
string var1;
string var2;
}
```

And i have another model who has `example` as property

**Model B**

```
public class padre
{
string another_var;
example ejemplo;
}
```

I'm having issues when i want to recive `example` from a `padre` view

**View**

```
@model padre
<div>@Html.Partial(_PartialViewExample, Model.ejemplo)</div>
```

**PartialView**

```
@model example
@* some coding *@
```

Thats what i'm trying, but i'm getting a

> System.InvalidOperationException

that tells me that the `PartialView` expects a `example` model and I'm sending it a `padre` model

Is the problem understood?

Thanks so much, and sry about my horrible english!

Comment: that's cause of `@model example`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `Html.RenderPartial()` instead?

Comment: I'm sory, i write bad, i was trying `Html.Partial()`, but i try with `Html.RenderPartial()` and i got the same exception :S

Comment: @Rahul yes it is, it has some solution? to not be forced to use `@model padre` in the `PartialView`?

Comment: You missing the quotes on partial helper, no? 
`<div>@Html.Partial("_PartialViewExample", Model.ejemplo)</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `ejemplo` property is not `null`. If you're passing `null` into `Html.Partial`, MVC will think that you pass object of `padre` class. In this case you can write something like `@Html.Partial("_PartialViewExample", (example)Model.ejemplo)` of course.

P.S. Please don't name classes starting from lowercase letter. There are some naming conventions in C# that developers should respect ;)

Comment: Thanks! you save my day :D